# System of 7 equations and 3 unknowns in probability

Tags: probability, systems-of-equations

I have the following data:
$P(A\cap B^c \cap C^c)=0.14$, $P(A^c\cap B \cap C^c)=0.1$, $P(A^c\cap B^c \cap C)=0.15$, $P(A\cap B \cap C^c)=0.13$, $P(A\cap B^c \cap C)=0.12$, $P(A^c\cap B \cap C)=0.16$ and $P(A^c\cap B^c \cap C^c)=0.16$. I must find $P(A),P(B)$ and $P(C)$.

What I came up with was to do $P(A)=x$, $P(B)=y$ and $P(C)=z$, and considering that the events are independent form the system of equations

$x(1-y)(1-z)=0.14$

$(1-x)y(1-z)=0.1$

$(1-x)(1-y)(1-z)=0.09$

$xy(1-z)=0.13$

$x(1-y)z=0.12$

$(1-x)yz=0.16$

$(1-x)(1-y)z=0.15$

according to wolfram said system of seven equations has no solution,
is there something wrong with my approach?

Comment: "*Considering that the events are independent*"  How did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: For a correct approach, recognize that $\Pr(A) = \Pr(A\cap B\cap C)+\Pr(A\cap B^c\cap C)+\Pr(A\cap B\cap C^c)+\Pr(A\cap B^c\cap C^c)$ and similar as per [Law of Total Probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability).  Perhaps organize your thoughts using a Venn Diagram.

Comment: the problem is not specific

Comment: I do not understand your latest comment.  What do you mean by "the problem is not specific"?  Did you or did you not understand my previous comments?  Do you or do you not recognize that my comment leads directly to an answer and is applicable to your current scenario?

Comment: I meant that I assumed that the events are independent since the problem does not specify that they are not.

Comment: Regarding your second comment, thank you, I will attack the problem from there

Comment: "*I assumed that the events are independent since the problem does not specify that they are not*"  You should **never** do this.

Answer (score 1):

HINT...you have assumed incorrectly that all these events are independent which gives you wrong equations.
Why not start by drawing a Venn diagram?